# How to prevent Error inflating class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView?

Tags: android, crash, exoplayer2.x, inflate-exception, invocationtargetexception

Exoplayer2 is working fine in devices like Samsung, Vivo, Xiaomi, etc on both release and debug build. But when I have released my app on the play store, it is throwing errors on some devices like nexus, pixel phones.

```
Crashlytics showing this error: Caused by android.view.InflateException: 
Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
```

I found some similar questions already raised about the same issue but nothing used for me. (**I am using the default player without any customized**)
can anyone help me to fix this issue?

My code:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
      android:id="@+id/playerView"
      android:focusable="true"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
  />


 var player:SimpleExoPlayer?=null


  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.pdf_view_normal)

       player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this)
       val mediaDataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, getUserAgent(this, "demo.smart.com"))

      val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory)
                                        .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(""))

        with(player) {
               this!!.prepare(mediaSource, false, false)
               playWhenReady = true
                     }

        playerView.setShutterBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        playerView.player = player
        playerView.requestFocus()

}


override fun onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy()

        if(player!=null){
                player!!.stop()
         }
 }
```

Gradle

```
android{
   
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    ..

}


 implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.8'
```

All log for your reference

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{demo.smart.com.Viewer}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView

Caused by android.view.InflateException
Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
```

Comment: have you find the solution? i'm getting the same issue inandroidx.media3:media3-exoplayer